# Function not showing correct result

Tags: javascript

I have written this code

```
var foo = {
    x:2,
    baz: {
        x:1,
        bar:function() {
            return this.x;
        }
    }
}

var go = foo.baz.bar;
console.log(go());
```

The answer is undefined. But why?
When `go` maps to the function `bar`, it should return `2` because we have  `x:2` in `foo`.

Comment: **1.** `this` context depends on how the function is being called **2** **Answer** `go()` ==> `window.go()`.

Comment: thanks man. Add in answer and i will tick it..

Comment: @Tushar but what about x:2.. this.x should show 2 right?

Comment: Depends, if the context is foo, yes, this.x will be 2, but if the context is foo.baz, this.x will be 1

Comment: That's what the first comment says, `this` is `window` when called as `go()`. If you try `foo.baz.bar()`, `this` will be set to `foo` and it'll return correct result. **Solution:** `var go = foo.baz.bar.bind(foo);`

Comment: but why dosent it show 2 here when we want this.x  i mean why undefined when we have 2 as a value of the foo,s property.

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini run my code snippet to understand what is going on, I don't believe Tushar can say it more clear that he already said it :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, as Tushar said in the comments:

> **this** context depends on how the function is being called

Here's a snippet to illustrate some ways to achieve what you want, using `bind`, `call` or `apply`

```js
var foo ={
  x:2,
  baz: {
    x:1,
    bar:function() {
      
      return this.x;
    }
  }
};

var go = foo.baz.bar;
console.log("go(): " + go()); //this === window, window.x is undefined
console.log("go.bind(foo)(): " +go.bind(foo)()); //this === foo, foo.x is 2
console.log("go.bind(foo.baz)(): " +go.bind(foo.baz)()); //this === foo.baz, foo.baz.x is 1

console.log("go.apply(foo): " + go.apply(foo)); //2
console.log("go.apply(foo.baz): " + go.apply(foo.baz)); //1

console.log("go.call(foo): " + go.call(foo)); //2
console.log("go.call(foo.baz): " + go.call(foo.baz)); //1

var x = 100;
console.log(go()); //100, since window.x == 100
```